# Ensure consistency when caching data in after_commit hooks

Tags: ruby, activerecord, concurrency, thread-safety

For a specific database table, we need an in-memory cache of this data that is always in-sync with the database. My current attempt is to write the changes to the cache in an `after_commit` hook - this way we make sure not to write any changes to the cache that could get reverted later.

However, this strategy is vulnerable to the following scenario:

1. Thread A locks and updates record, stores value `1`
2. Thread A commits the change
3. Thread B locks and updates record, stores value `2`
4. Thread B commits the change
5. Thread B runs the `after_commit` hook, so the cache now has value `2`
6. Thread A runs the `after_commit` hook, so the cache now has value `1` but should have value `2`

Am I right about this problem and how would one solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we came up with is to lock the cache for read / write `before_commit` and unlock it in the `after_commit`. This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about this problem.

There is a `after_save` callback that runs within the same transaction. You might want to use that one instead of the `after_commit` hook that run after the transaction.

But than you will need to deal with a rolled back transaction yourself.

Or you might want to write your caching method in a way that does not depend on a specific instance. But instead caches the latest version that is found in the database by reloading the record from the database first.

But even than: Multithreaded systems are hard to keep in sync. And you cannot even ensure if the first or the second update send to your cache would be stored, because the caching system might be multi-threaded too.

You might want to read about [different consistency models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Since the cache involves a whole tree structure, handling a rollback there would practically mean to re-implement  a db-like transaction handling for the cache as well. Just invalidating the cache and reloading it later would also be a solution, but very complicated for a tree structure. Is there no go-to solution for these kinds of problems?

Comment: How often to the records change? How often do you read the records? How complex is the structure in the cache? Perhaps it might be possible to optimize your database schema for reading instead of relying on caching for reading?

Comment: The records can change quite often and it's a tree structure of 50-100k records, so I think it's not an option reading this (on every request) without caching. The query is a nested query which takes about 1.4 seconds and I don't see much potential for optimization there.